# Do computer lens have side effects?

Tags: eye, glasses, eye-strain

I was introduced by a spectacles shop about a new technology called computer lens which block blue light that is harmful to eyes. He says it reduces eye-strain for workers who need to be face a computer monitor for hours every day.

More importantly, are there any side effects or harmful effects that one need to be aware about computer lens? I am fine with paying more but not ok if the "gimmick" is harmful to my eyes.

Comment: Research has already shown that blue light blocking lenses have shown no evidence on curing eye strain: https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/30570598/ and https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/32007978/. What you really need to do, is to get 8 hours sleep each night, close your eyes after 20 minutes of computer use and make sure you get a well balanced diet of properly cooked food.